# Self closing .js toggled menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Friends,

I've been using the .js navigation menu toggle implementation from the following link: [click here.](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz)

```
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
// based on Todd Motto functions
// http://toddmotto.com/labs/reusable-js/

// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + '');
}
// addClass
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
// removeClass
function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}
// toggleClass
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, " " ) + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace( " " + className + " " , " " );
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
}
```

I want to modify the code here so that the menu box with the links automatically closes after the menu button has been clicked. I guess I'm gonna need some extra .onclick function. Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener which triggers the `toggleClass()` function once any menu item has been clicked.

```
var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

for (i=0; i<menuLinks.length; i++) {
  menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggleClass(theToggle, 'on');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need some extra click function on menu button. I have created that extra click for you please have a look into it. I have take reference for same link which you provided.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].onclick = function() {
     toggleClass(theToggle, 'on');
     return false;
  }
}
```